# Query elements where relationship is null

Tags: graphql, graphcool

If I have a simple schema like:

```
type Author @model { 
  id: ID! @isUnique 
  posts: [Post!]!  @relation(name: "AuthorOfPost")
}
type Post @model {
  id: ID! @isUnique
  author: Author @relation(name: "AuthorOfPost")
}
```

How can I query all Posts that do not have an author?

Unfortunately, I cannot find something in the `authorFilter` like `id_is_null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this!

```
query PostsWithAuthor {
  allPosts(filter: { author: null }) {
    id
    author {
      id
    }
  }
}
```